# Ajax SOAP Cross Domain ‘POST’ bad request 400

Tags: ajax, soap, xmlhttprequest, webservice-client, bad-request

I was stuck on below the 'soapRequest', I try to test my netbeans connect cross domain access but keep on failing, anyone can help me point out my mistake?

Add on, I installed 'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin' on my google chrome browser and also tried to browser poster plugin to test the 'get' and 'post' are work.

```
function submitLogIn(username, passw) {
    var userId = document.getElementById(username).value;
    var userPass = document.getElementById(passw).value;

    var soap1 = '<soap:Envelope ';
    var soap2 = 'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ';
    var soap3 = 'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ';
    var soap4 = 'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> ';
    var soap5 = '<soap:Body> ';
    var soap6 = '<Login xmlns="S2Ed"> ';
    var soap7 = '<userid>' + userId + '</userid> ';
    var soap8 = '<password>' + userPass + '</password> ';
    var soap9 = '</Login>';
    var soap10 = '</soap:Body>';
    var soap11 = '</soap:Envelope>';
    var soapMessage = soap1 + soap2 + soap3 + soap4 + soap5 + soap6 + soap7 + soap8 + soap9 + soap10 + soap11;

    // Call + ing...... 
    CallAjax(soapMessage);
}

function CallAjax(soapMessage) {
    console.log(soapMessage.toString());

    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: http://localhost:5566/Test.svc,
        // contentType: 'application/soap+xml',
        // content-Type: 'text/plain',
        contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        async: true, 
        dataType: 'xml',
        crossDomain: true,
        // processData: false,
        headers: {
            SOAPAction: 'S2Ed/App/Login'
        },
        data: soapMessage,
        success: function (soapResponse) {
            console.log(soapResponse);
            console.log(soapResponse.toString());
            console.log(soapResponse.toJSON());
            console.log(soapResponse.toXML());
        },
        error: function (soapResponse) {
            alert("Failed SOAP ");
        }
    });
}
```

Below is the error message
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. (15:39:52:688 | warning, deprecation)
  at public_html/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) (15:39:58:281 | error, network)
  at http://localhost:5566/Test.svc

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5566/Test.svc. Invalid HTTP status code 400 (15:39:58:282 | error, javascript)
  at public_html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Error 400 usually means you submitted something to the server which the server does not like. I.e submitting the name in the age field, etc

To add on, it might be possible that your request xml is wrong. Can you print it in console and see if it's a valid xml?